# How to solve equations in python

Tags: python, equation, solver, equation-solving

I try to write a script that simulates a resistor. It takes 2 arguments for example P and R and it should calculate all missing values of this resistor.
The problem is that I don't want to write every single possible equation for every value. This means I want to write something like `(U=RxI, R=U/R, I=U/R , P=UxI)` and the script should then complete all equation with the given values for every equation.

For example, something like this:

```
in R=10
in I=5
out U=R*I
out P=I**2 * R
```

Comment: I'm not sure that you can avoid writing all functions... you maybe can but using some symbolic library, i think it's not a good idea..

Comment: You can write generic function that accepts those inputs and calculates the missing parameters/values. Required values can be passed as Null so you can find those Null values inside function body

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla python, there is no solution as general as the one you are looking for.

The typical solution would be to write an algorithm for every option (only given `U`, only given `R`) and then logically select which option to execute.

You may also want to consider using a module like [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org), which has a solver module that may be more up your alley.

Answer (score 2):

You can use https://pypi.org/project/Equation/ Packages.

#### Example

```
>>> from Equation import Expression
>>> fn = Expression("sin(x+y^2)",["y","x"])
>>> fn
sin((x + (y ^ (2+0j))))
>>> print fn
\sin\left(\left(x + y^{(2+0j)}\right)\right)
>>> fn(3,4)
(0.42016703682664092+0j)
```

#### Sympy

Second: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki

- Arbitrary precision integers, rationals and floats, as well as symbolic expressions
- Simplification (e.g. ( abb + 2bab ) → (3ab^2)), expansion (e.g. ((a+b)^2) → (a^2 + 2ab + b^2)), and other methods of rewriting expressions
- Functions (exp, log, sin, ...)
- Complex numbers (like exp(I*x).expand(complex=True) → cos(x)+I*sin(x))
- Taylor (Laurent) series and limits
- Differentiation and integration